# How to remove someone from People results in Google Photos?

Tags: google-photos, facial-recognition

When searching for photos in the new Google Photos app, the facial recognition feature culls together a directory of different people to allow you to search your photos by individuals. Currently, you can only remove batches of photos from the person's search results, but not their record altogether unless you delete all the photos. Any ideas?

Comment: I have the same problem. I can't remove (it's different from move to trash), i just want to remove it from the albums not deleting it, someone can help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same problem. Here's how I fixed it.

1. On a PC, go to: https://photos.google.com/people
2. Click on the 3-bubble menu top right
3. Click on "Show & hide people"

Then click on the faces you want to hide.

Comment: I have multiple google accounts (e.g. https://photos.google.com/u/1/search/xyz123), so I used this URL and the directions worked: https://photos.google.com/u/#/people

Comment: How did you know to go to that url (.../people)? It's obvious when you see it, but where did you first find out about it?